# How to give 3 different color for div's in loop in php

Tags: php, html, css

Trying to give 3 different color for div's in loop in php, now its working only two .how can i impliment alternative color for div.? Here what I want.

[image]

**style**

```
.redBackground { background-color:#F00; }
.blueBackground { background-color:#03F;}
.greenBackground { background-color:#6F3; }
```

**php**

```
        <?php
        $new= mysql_query("select * from tbl_news");
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($new))
        {

        $x++; 

        $class = ($x%2 == 0)? 'redBackground': 'blueBackground' ;


        echo "<tr class='$class'>";



        $id = $row['id'];

        $news = $row['news'];

        ?>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 news_main_div">


        <div class="md-trigger"  data-modal="modal-11">
        <div <?php echo "<tr class='$class'> ";?>>
        <h1 style=" margin-bottom:5px;">
        <strong ><?php echo $news ?></strong>
        </h1></div></div><?php } ?>
```

Comment: want colors in continues order like first while then gray then red or in random order?

Comment: Do ***NOT*** use `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 and are removed from PHP 7. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use color array like below

```
$color_array = array('whiteBackground', 'grayBackground', 'blueBackground');

$x=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($new)){
    $x++;
    $class = $color_array[$x%3];
}
```

And in future, if you want to more color, then simply add color-class in array and change in `$color_arrar[$x%n]`, where **n=number_of_color**

If you want random color, then use below code

```
$color_arrar = array('whiteBackground ','grayBackground ','blueBackground ');
$size_of_array = sizeof($color_arrar);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($new)){
    $n = rand(0,$size_of_array-1);
    $class = $color_arrar[$n%3];
}
```

Comment: What does [$x%n] mean here? what does %n do actually?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
if($x%3 == 0)
  $class = 'greenBackground';
else if($x%2 == 0 )
   $class = 'redBackground'; 
else
   $class = 'blueBackground';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in random order you can use `array_rand` function

```
$color = array("redBackground", "blueBackground", "greenBackground");
$colorValue = array_rand($color, 1);

$class = $color [$colorValue];
```